# How to join 3 tables based on ID using LINQ SQL join? C# MVC (.NET Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 3 tables/Entities called Person, PersonPhone and EmailAddress. All tables ID using the same ID called BusinessEntityID. "BusinessEntity" is also a table.

I have created a ViewModel to pass to my View which will display some data:

```
@model CoreTutorials1.ViewModels.PersonIndexViewModel

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>@Model.Person.FirstName @Model.Person.LastName</title>
</head>
<body>
    <dl>
        <dt><b>First Name: </b></dt>
        <dd>@Model.Person.FirstName</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt><b>Last Name: </b></dt>
        <dd>@Model.Person.LastName</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt><b>Phone: </b></dt>
        <dd>@Model.PersonPhone.PhoneNumber</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt><b>Email Address: </b></dt>
        <dd>@Model.EmailAddress.EmailAddress1</dd>
    </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

In my Controller I've already tried to do the following (sorta):

```
// GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // will grab the first Person from our DbSet from our db
            //var person = db.Person.FirstOrDefault();
            var person = db.Person.Where(x => x.BusinessEntityId == 1).FirstOrDefault();

            var a = from ea in db.EmailAddress
                    join p in db.Person on ea.BusinessEntityId equals p.BusinessEntityId
                    join pp in db.PersonPhone on p.BusinessEntityId equals pp.BusinessEntityId
                    where p.BusinessEntityId == person.BusinessEntityId
                    select new
                    {

                    };

            PersonIndexViewModel vm = new PersonIndexViewModel()
            {
                Person = person,
                PersonPhone = person.PersonPhone.FirstOrDefault(),
                EmailAddress = person.EmailAddress.FirstOrDefault()
            };

            // pass the viewmodel so it's data can be accessed in the view (Person, PersonPhone, EmailAddress)
            return View(vm);
        }
```

My main goal is that I can attach PhoneNumber & EmailAddress to the Person object, so that it can be used in my ViewModel after I assign the values like so:

```
PersonPhone = person.PersonPhone.FirstOrDefault(),
EmailAddress = person.EmailAddress.FirstOrDefault()
```

Then in my ViewModel I can do for example

```
@Model.PersonPhone.PhoneNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = from p in db.Person
             where p.BusinessEntityId == 1
             select new PersonIndexViewModel
             {
                 Person = p,
                 PersonPhone = p.PersonPhone.FirstOrDefault(),
                 EmailAddress = p.EmailAddress.FirstOrDefault()
             };


    return View(vm.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

if you want show multiply phons/mails per person, you need change the `PersonIndexViewModel.PersonPhone` and `PersonIndexViewModel.EmailAddress` types to List<>, and fill it with `ToList()` instead `FirstOrDefault()` and in razor view write a `foreach` statment.

Comment: When changing my query to yours and running the app, I get the following error message:

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[CoreTutorials1.ViewModels.PersonIndexViewModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'CoreTutorials1.ViewModels.PersonIndexViewModel'.

Comment: thanks it works now :) So if you have the same ID connecting 3 tables as their primary key, you can do it as above, but if you have say 3 tables with foreign keys etc. you have to do it differently?

Comment: same thing, if you have NavigationProperies (such p.PersonPhone) as here.